Data Ingestion through DataNodes on HDFS
I am ingesting or writing data on HDFS. I have 5 data nodes, and I wrote a PySpark script to ingest data from each data node. I am doing this because I want a replication factor of 1. However, when I start writing data from the NameNode, it only writes data to one node and takes up storage on that data node.
The problem I am facing is that I sometimes get a missing block exception, and when the load increases, the data ingestion time increases exponentially. I want to know the proper way to deal with this issue, and whether writing data from the data nodes is a good approach.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Replication factor of 1 only takes storage of one datanode, yes... And frequent writes will slow down the namenode, yes. It's not clear why you want 1 replica as this will increase the likelihood of missing blocks and you have up to 5 datanodes that replicas can exist

I want to set the replication factor to 1 due to storage constraints. I have 5 DataNodes, each with 114TB of storage, but I am processing 13TB of data per day. The requirement is to maintain data for six months. Since I am storing it in Parquet format, which compresses the data to approximately 3TB per day, my calculation is 3TB * 180 days = 540TB. Therefore, I will need 540TB of storage. Since 114TB * 5 = 570TB, I have 570TB of storage available. So I can't increase the replication factor.
